# module "speechRecognition" is not loading in python even when it is installed

Tags: python

While making this simple code on vs code, using modules "pyttsx3" and "speechRecognition".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDbHT.png)
The python was not importing it it was continuously giving me this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hIBN.png)

But when I tried installing it python was saying that it was installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpxN3.png)

I even tried Uninstalling and then installing it, But it never worked
:(

Comment: from the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/): `import speech_recognition as sr`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.